# Disable a plugin's widget

Tags: widgets

I wonder if possible to disable a widget that belongs to a plugin that is currently active w/o touching the plugin code.

For sample, I normally use a code like this to disable wordpress widgets,

```
 unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Text');
```

Now, I want to also deactivate let's say for sample the widget called "The other Widget"

is that possible?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: you can't unregister it in your theme's function.php using a higher priority than the plugin is using?

Comment: that was my first thought, however didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `widgets_init` hook with a high priority
for example this will remove the default WP Widgets

```
function unregister_default_wp_widgets() {
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Pages');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Calendar');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Archives');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Links');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Meta');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Search');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Text');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Categories');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Posts');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Comments');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_RSS');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud');
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'unregister_default_wp_widgets', 1);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but as I showed in my example, I've already tried with it, however I'm looking to disable other plugins which are from other plugins, like nextgen gallery, or meteor slide, or whatever. Any guessing?